# Cypress - How to get third element in order in method CONTAINS?

Tags: cypress, contains

**by.contains('text')**    -     Find the first element containing some text

How can i do something like this?    -    **by.contains('text').eq(3)**   OR   **by.contains('text')[3]**

These two methods do not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to directly assert the text of the third element then you can use `eq(2)`

```
cy.get(selector).eq(2).should('have.text', 'some text')
```

Comment: Problem is, I need to get element ONLY by containing the text not by selector.